# Is the apple-app-site-association implementation safe?

Tags: ios, security, ios-universal-links, app-site-association

By implementing universal links, you end up with an `apple-app-site-association` file that you put in the root of your server. The file contains both `bundleID` and `teamID`. **Is this safe?**

I can clearly download e.g. Google’s one and get their IDs since the scenario is always the same.

Comment: And what do you plan to do with does ID's, since you can also get them from the IPA that is backuped by iTunes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no security risk from displaying the bundle ID and team ID. It is not possible to use these two pieces of information for anything (either productive or dangerous) without also having access to your Apple Developer account password.